# awk behaves differently for different Ubuntu versions

Tags: awk

Why awk returns 1 running this command on Ubuntu 20.04 (focal):

```
TEST=4.0; echo $TEST | awk '{ print($1 >= 4.1) }'
```

But returns 0 running this command on Ubuntu 18.04 (bionic).

It is clear to me that the awk versions are different but how is the behavior to be explained.

I would be happy if someone could give me some hints.

Comment: Running `awk --version` on both systems and including the output in your question would be a place to start. Nobody is going to install two different versions of Ubuntu just so they can answer your question, but someone _may_ be willing to install two versions of awk (particularly if they use a package manager, like [Nix](https://nixos.org/), that makes it easy).

Comment: That said, are you 100% certain you tested with _exactly_ this line on both systems, not just code you think should behave identically to it?

Comment: (Also, I don't advise using the word "returns" here -- what you mean is that it _outputs_ that value, right? The _returned_ value is something different -- specifically, the returned value is the exit status left in `$?`)

Comment: I just happen to have Ubuntu 20.04 running in a VM and your test code generates a `0` for me (`awk --version` ==> `GNU Awk 5.0.1`); though to be honest ... I don't recall if that's the default installation version or if I updated it; and ... nope ... I don't have access to Ubuntu 18.04 (though by itself that may not address the issue since, as Charles Duffy has pointed out, depends on what version of `awk` has been installed)

Comment: Might be a locale difference as well. Post the output of the `locale` command on each OS.

Comment: In addition to locale settings changing as @glennjackman mentions, older releases of GNU awk do accommodate your locale setting for decimal point when doing comparisons while newer releases ignore your locale for that and use `.` by default unless called with `--use-lc-numeric` or `--posix` (discouraged), see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Locale-influences-conversions, so you could be tripping over that too. Execute `export LC_ALL=C` (a locale that uses `.` as the decimal point) then run your code to see what happens.

Comment: The problem was actually due to the locale differences. My Ubuntu 20.04 (focal) was set to german and awk couldn't handle the decimal point. Thank you!